# Operation class "render" does not exist in "App\Entity\Engine\Car" (custom operation API platform with YAML resource)

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I would like to create a custom operation for my API Platform.

But documentation is poor if you want t create custom operation with resources YAML file.

*I declared that :*

```
resources:

  App\Entity\Engine\Car:
    security: 'is_granted("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN")'
    itemOperations:
      render:
        method: 'GET'
        path: '/engine/{id}/render'
        uriTemplate: '/engine/{id}/render'
        controller: App\Controller\Api\EngineRenderController
    operations:
      render:
        method: 'GET'
        path: '/engine/{id}/render'
        uriTemplate: '/engine/{id}/render'
        controller: App\Controller\Api\EngineRenderController
```

*with this controller API :*

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Controller\Api;
    
    use App\Entity\Engine\Car;
    
    class EngineRenderController
    {
        public function __invoke(): array
        {
    
            return ['test' => 'I be back'];
    
        }
    }
```

*It generate his :*

*Operation class "render" does not exist in "App\Entity\Engine\Car" (/var/www/project/config/api_platform/resources.yaml) in . (which is being imported from "/var/www/project/config/routes/api_platform.yaml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "api_platform" type.*

What is the exact declaration can use ?

Why declare anything in my entity if a use resources.yaml and controller API ?

*I just use this declaration :*

```
itemOperations:
  render:
    method: 'GET'
    path: '/engine/{id}/render'
    uriTemplate: '/engine/{id}/render'
    controller: App\Controller\Api\EngineRenderController
```

My swagger page generate correctly but nothing about my path api or method api with name 'render'

**How correctly create custom operation with YAML format and API Platform context ?**

Comment: /engine/{id}/render is not a valid uri until I know. ApiPlatform reject uri's with more than 1 level. Only uri variables are accepted in subsequent levels. Try /engine/{action}/{id}, then call /engine/render/{id}. If you have several actions use a switch to handle each one.

Comment: You can explore also the routePrefix option

Comment: About my first comment, try to use an StateProvider instead of a controller

Answer (score 0):

lot of time had passed and i change lot of things. But I can share my config which run for custom rendering methods API Platform like this :

**api_platform.yaml**

```
api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /api
```

**resources.yaml**

resources:

```
App\Entity\Module\Car:
    normalizationContext:
        groups: ['read']
    denormalizationContext:
        groups: ['write']
    security: 'is_granted("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN")'
    operations:
        ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection: ~
        ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get:
        render:
          class: ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get
          uriTemplate: '/cars/{ID}/render'
          controller: App\Controller\Api\CarRenderController
```

**CarRenderController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Api;

use App\Entity\Car;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Attribute\AsController;

#[AsController()]
class CarRenderController extends AbstractController
{
    private ManagerRegistry $em;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->em = $doctrine;

    }

    public function __invoke(Car $data): array
    {
        $items = $data->getItems();
        $items[0]->getTitle();

        return ['data' => $items[0]->getTitle()];

    }
}
```

Pay attention of :

- 'AsController' PHP attribute onto CustomController for API
- declaration of GET operations into resources.yaml because lot of examples in the web